# understanding the usage of this inside

Tags: javascript, jquery, promise

i was just going through the documentation of the $.Deffered in jQuery and came across the following example :

```
$.fn.bindOnce = function( event, callback ) {
    var element = $( this[ 0 ] ),
        defer = element.data( "bind_once_defer_" + event );

    if ( !defer ) {
        defer = $.Deferred();
        function deferCallback() {
            element.unbind( event, deferCallback );
            defer.resolveWith( this, arguments ); // What is `this` and `arguments` here ?  
        }
        element.bind( event, deferCallback )
        element.data( "bind_once_defer_" + event , defer );
    }

    return defer.done( callback ).promise();
};
```

you can see the same example **[HERE](https://learn.jquery.com/code-organization/deferreds/examples/#one-time-event)** , now the code is not overly complex , but there are a few things that don't quite make sense, example, see the below snippet of code :

```
function deferCallback() {
            element.unbind( event, deferCallback );
            defer.resolveWith( this, arguments );
        }
```

the code is pretty standard, what i don't understand though is what is `this` pointing to in the above code ? i have no clue as to what this is pointing to in the above code .

The **[documentation](https://api.jquery.com/deferred.resolveWith/)** does't say much about this method too.

can anybody explain ? i understand that this is the context , but what i don't understand is that in the code snippet that i have mentioned above , what will this be pointing to ?

Also i fail to understand what part resolveWith plays in the above snippet of code anyways. my only guess is that `resolveWith()` results in the execution of the below line of code :

```
return defer.done( callback ).promise();
```

again i am not too sure about this .

Answer (score 1):

> fail to understand what part resolveWith plays in the above snippet of
>   code anyways.

---

At [linked page](https://learn.jquery.com/code-organization/deferreds/examples/#one-time-event)

The code works as follows:

- Check if the element already has a deferred attached for the given
  event
- if not, create it and make it so it is resolved when the event is
  fired the first time around
- then attach the given callback to the deferred and return the promise

---

`.resolveWith()` can set the `context` , `this` within `.done()` , `.fail()` `.notify()` callbacks

Answer (score 1):

> what will this be pointing to ?

I believe they've intended for the `this` keyword to point to the element(s) that `$.fn.bindOnce` was chained against but it is being referenced within a new function which won't have the same scope.

You can tell deferCallback what it's `this` should be though with `.bind()`:

```
// use `.bind()` to set the `this` keyword in
// deferCallback to the `this` in bindOnce 
element.bind( event, deferCallback.bind(this) );
```

Currently, without `.bind()` the `this` will be `window`.